# Fixed sized items in Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am rather new to this whole Swing, but nevertheless it already got me quite annoyed.

I am trying to do something simple, that behaves like WPF's list with custom item template. That is, item are of fixed size and as it overflows the given area a scroll bar pops up.
[image: desired outcome]

And I've been trying and trying, but I just can't get it to work. The closest I got was with BoxLayout, the problem there however, is that if there are too few items to take available space, they get stretched -.-
[image: closest I got]

I bet there is some simple way to achieve that, I just don't know about. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code I got (java):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel itemsPanel;
    private JButton addButton;

    public MainFrame()
    {
        // create components
        itemsPanel = new JPanel();
        addButton = new JButton("Add");

        // layout
        itemsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(itemsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        buttons.add(addButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(itemsPanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // actions
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                itemsPanel.add(new SampleItem());
                itemsPanel.revalidate();
            }
        });

        // frame size and close action
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension size = new Dimension(300, 300);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class SampleItem extends JPanel
{
    public SampleItem()
    {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I ended up writing custom renderer and editor thanks to rcook's answer.

**EDIT2:**

Eh, after turning it in, I got scolded really badly for this... Apparently the problem is that JScrollPane resizes viewport so that the control fills all available space and the solution is to create `JPanel implements Scrollable` and return false in `public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()`. Oh well, I hope someone will find it useful, editors are just so much pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a JList, put it inside a JScrollPane, put that within a pane in the middle part of a BorderLayout; BorderLayout is the default for a JFrame, so you may not need to create one.  Put the lower button on the bottom portion of the BorderLayout.

Comment: Erm. I did it just now.. but now I can't see anything on the list. I did consider that option though, and I'd totally go with custom renderer/editor **if not that** I intend to have fairly complex control inside of that "list".

Comment: If you can't see anything in the list, then there's obviously something wrong with the code.  If debugging it doesn't tell you what's wrong, then write a little program with a list and get that to work, then progress outward.  If the little program doesn't work, you can post the whole thing; SO is real good about helping solve those problems.  I do not suggest another vague question with a heap of code that you apparently want someone to debug.  I don't know what you mean by "if not that ..." -- a complex control inside the list is exactly what calls for a custom renderer/editor.